# Keeping batch message history in iOS device

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I've implemented an IM messaging module in my app, but there is an issue about keeping messages as history. In my model, I am pushing all messages with services and new messages comes with socket.

I think saving message history on device is better way to save bandwidth on service. I am thinking to use `NSUserDefaults` for keeping data, but I really do not know about performance issue. Is there any better way to keep huge rows in device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is small data then use NSUserDefaults.

But if data is in large amount use CoreData or Sqlite. It is safe and secure.

Apple has made CoreDate more good in terms of performance.

Sqlite3 is more useful for keeping large database and to access to the database elements. You can sort the items of sqlite3 database, you can search very fast for item in Sqlite3 database.

You're not going to see a speed difference, but it's still best to pick the correct mechanism for what you're doing. If it's just preferences then use NSUserDefaults, otherwise I would serialize your objects to a plist. If you're new to Cocoa I would avoid Core Data and even sqlite at first, to give yourself a chance to learn the basics first.

Comment: I think , using Sqllite3 is the best way to get data with specific userid. I will not have any chance to fetch data using specific user id except using Sqllite3 ?

Comment: And rate my question too pls :)